# Is there a way to render single channel greyscale images using glDrawPixels?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, opengl-compat

I'm trying to create a program that handles images of all types by using oiio and OpenGL (simple functions, nothing too crazy).

I've got 4 channel and 3 channel images working, I'm just not sure how to render greyscale (1 channel) images.

```
if (channels == 4){
   glDrawPixels(W, H, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, img);
}
```

I'm hoping the answer is something like the snippet above.

Comment: Have a look at [glDrawPixels](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glDrawPixels.xml). IMHO, replacing `GL_RGBA` with `GL_LUMINANCE` should do the job for greyscale images (with 1 channel).

Comment: @Scheff Thanks! That fixed it. I wasn’t sure what that command was as it didn’t sound like something I needed to be using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've to an image where each pixel is a single grayscale value, then you can use the *format* `GL_LUMINANCE`. See [`glDrawPixels`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml).
The luminance value converted and is set to the red, green, and blue color channel, the alpha channel will be set 1.

If the type of each pixel is a 32 bit floating point value, the the format is `GL_FLOAT`:

```cpp
glDrawPixels(W, H, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_FLOAT, img);
```

If the grayscale value is encoded in a byte, then you've to use the unsigned normalized floating point format `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`:

```cpp
glDrawPixels(W, H, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img);
```